# Load a npz in numpy from bytes

Tags: python, numpy, byte

I have a npz file saved from numpy that I can load by using `numpy.load(mynpzfile)`. However, I would like to save this file as a part of a binary file, packed with another file. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Saving file jointly
input1 = open('animagefile.png', 'rb').read()
input2 = open('npzfile.npz', 'rb').read()
filesize = len(input1).to_bytes(4, 'big')

output = filesize + input1 + input2

with open('Output.bin', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(output)

# Open them
input1 = open('Output.bin', 'rb').read()
filesize2 = int.from_bytes(input1[:4], "big")

segmentation = Image.open(BytesIO(input1[4:4+filesize2])) 
# THIS LINE GIVES ME AN ERROR
layouts = np.frombuffer(input2[4+filesize2:])
```

However, when reading back the npz I get an error. I have tried load and frombuffer, and both give me an error:

- frombuffer: `ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size`
- load: `ValueError: embedded null byte`

What can I do?

Comment: A `npz` file is actually `zip` archive.  I don't know exactly what `input2` is, but I doubt if it's meaningful, or something that can be joined with another bytestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line should be `input1`, not `input2`. Also, guessing from the error message, you forgot to put `BytesIO`.

```py
layouts = np.load(BytesIO(input1[4+filesize2:]))
                  ^^^^^^^      ^
```

Comment: Ups... well seen!